# moz-border-radius not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a navigation bar so that when you hover over the link, it changes colour and the bottom left and right corners are rounded. This seems to work fine on chrome and on some versions of ie but not on firefox. Am i using the wrong code or does firefox simply not support border radius? I am using firefox version 22.

**CSS**

```
    #nav li:hover a,#nav .active a
{
color:#4D4D4D!important;
-moz-border-radius-bottom-right:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottom-left:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;


}
```

Comment: did you try just `border-radius` without the vendor prefix?

Comment: You are not using standard property

Answer (score 6):

If you use a prefixed property, usually you should include the non-prefixed version as well:

```
#nav li:hover a,#nav .active a
{
     -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
          border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
          border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
```

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius), Firefox uses the unprefixed `border-radius` in its current versions (since version 4.0 actually).

Comment: oh i see, that is what was missing from my code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's always useful to check caniuse.com, in this case: http://caniuse.com/border-radius

It'll let you know if a feature is available or not.

Edit:
But specifically it seems the moz vendor specific version should be

```
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:
```

as can be seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom-right-radius

Comment: awesome, thanks for the link. I'll take note of that